# DateTimeParseException not handling with try/catch Error Message

Tags: javafx

I am building an application where a user inputs a date in MM/dd/yyyy format in `DatePicker` and after hitting the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, it will advance to the next screen. I am trying to handle the `DateTimeParseException` error in the `KeyEvent`, but I get a `DateTimeParseException` error on the `alert.showAndWait()` line. The error window dialog still pops up as expected when I run the application.

```
private void switchToNewView(Window window) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/nextScreen.fxml"));
    Parent scene = loader.load();

    Stage stage = (Stage) window;
    stage.setScene(new Scene(scene));
    stage.show();
}

@FXML
void enterKey(KeyEvent event) throws DateTimeParseException{
        try{
            String inputDate = datePicker.getEditor().getText();

            // Format String inputDate to LocalDate
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
            LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.parse(inputDate, formatter); 
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                switchToNewView(datePicker.getScene().getWindow());
            }
        }
        catch(DateTimeParseException | IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR); //Alert dialog box
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid date");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
}
```

Full StackTrace: https://pastebin.com/TCQZbmfv

```
Error: Cannot invoke "java.time.LocalDate.until(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)" because "startDateInclusive" is null
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'test' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2108)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1936)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateTimeStringConverter$LdtConverter.fromString(LocalDateTimeStringConverter.java:203)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:134)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:45)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.commitValue(DatePicker.java:445)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.lambda$new$2(DatePicker.java:150)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node$FocusPropertyBase.notifyListeners(Node.java:8142)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node$17.notifyListeners(Node.java:8214)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.notifyFocusListeners(Node.java:8163)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:2120)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.lambda$new$5(Scene.java:2107)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:147)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:702)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window$1.setFocused(Window.java:160)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.setFocused(WindowHelper.java:112)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:65)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1259)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1238)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._setVisible(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.setVisible(Window.java:642)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.lambda$setVisible$2(WindowStage.java:514)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:442)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setVisible(WindowStage.java:510)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1186)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1254)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:277)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:467)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.HeavyweightDialog.showAndWait(HeavyweightDialog.java:162)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:346)
    at controller.FutureDuesMainController.enterKey(FutureDuesMainController.java:194)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1853)
    at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2194)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2715)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:542)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'test' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2108)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1936)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateTimeStringConverter$LdtConverter.fromString(LocalDateTimeStringConverter.java:203)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:134)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.util.converter.LocalDateStringConverter.fromString(LocalDateStringConverter.java:45)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.commitValue(DatePicker.java:445)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.DatePicker.lambda$new$2(DatePicker.java:150)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:360)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node$FocusPropertyBase.notifyListeners(Node.java:8142)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node$17.notifyListeners(Node.java:8214)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.notifyFocusListeners(Node.java:8163)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:2120)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.lambda$new$5(Scene.java:2107)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:147)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:91)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:702)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window$1.setFocused(Window.java:160)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowHelper.setFocused(WindowHelper.java:112)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:65)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:126)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1259)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1238)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._setVisible(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.setVisible(Window.java:635)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.lambda$setVisible$2(WindowStage.java:514)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:442)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setVisible(WindowStage.java:510)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1239)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:1264)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowCloseRequestHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(WindowCloseRequestHandler.java:45)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.closing(WindowPeerListener.java:100)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:147)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$4(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:178)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:176)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1259)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyClose(Window.java:1164)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried using `Platform.runLater()` in case this was due to an `IllegalStateException`, but that did not work.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
          Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR); //Alert dialog box
          alert.setTitle("Error");
          alert.setContentText("Please enter a valid date");
          alert.showAndWait();
          });
```

Comment: *"I get an error on the alert.showAndWait() line"* -> provide the stack trace as text formatted as code in the question.

Comment: What is  the value in the `inputDate` of the code `String inputDate = datePicker.getEditor().getText();`? You can try and print the value and see if it can be parsed into a date.

Comment: Class [DatePicker](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) inherits method `getValue` which returns a `LocalDate`. Hence no need to get the text and parse it.

Comment: And if you want to customize the format, then set the date picker's [`converter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#converterProperty) property (which holds a [`StringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/util/StringConverter.html)).

Comment: When using datepicker.getValue() and printing out the value, it always returns null

Comment: Then a date picker hasn't been picked in the date picker you are requesting the value from.  If you believe you have actually picked a date, and can't get its value, perhaps you did something like creating a new DatePicker instance instead of using the instance generated by the FXML Loader, but it is impossible to say without a [mcve] that can replicate your issue.